# null pointer exception when reading textfile

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to read a text file which contain English words and meaning of them by another language[sinhala] separated by a equal mark and split by a "|" mark. It looks like:

```
abmodality=අපමාතිය
abnegate=අයිතිවාසිකම අත්හරිනවා | ත්‍යජනය කරනවා | පිළිගැනීම අත්හරිනවා | මතය අත්හරිනවා
abnormal=අනියම් | අපසාමාන්‍ය | අප්‍රමත | අවප්‍රමාණ | අස්වාභාවික | අසාමාන්‍ය | පුදුම
abnormalism=අසාමාන්‍යභාවය
abnormality=අනියම් බව | අප්‍රමතිය | අසාමාන්‍යත්වය | අසාමාන්‍යය | විපරීතය | විශේෂය
abnormally=අනියම් ලෙසින් | අසාමාන්‍ය ලෙස | රියකට ගොඩ වී | විපරීතව
aboard=දුම්රියේ | නැවේ | යාත්‍රාවකට ගොඩ වී | යාත්‍රාවේ | වාහනයක
```

actually this is dictionary file and it contain all the English words stating a to z.I'm going to create MySQL db using this file because i can't insert all words and meanings by manually as it's too big.

so i created java program which create MySQL query programmatically so i can easily insert to my 1 to many database which has 2 tables.actually my problem is program give me a error and i found which line of text file give this error while reading.important and confusing fact is it's not a unique line,if i run my program 5 times error occurred while reading a different lines .

this is my code

```
                String[] parts ;
                String en;
                String[] sin;

                   try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\bac\\gui\\lktips-v3-lionlk.com\\a.txt"), "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {

                String s = br.readLine();

                parts = s.split("=");
                en=parts[0];
                sin=parts[1].split(" | ");

                 sb.append("INSERT INTO `singlish`.`eng` (`eid`, `eword`) VALUES ('"+stpoint+"', '"+en+"');")
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

                System.out.println(en);

                for(int i=0;i<sin.length;i++){

                sb.append("INSERT INTO `singlish`.`sng` (`eid`, `sword`) VALUES ('"+stpoint+"', '"+sin[i]+"');");
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                }

                System.out.println(""+stpoint);
                stpoint++;
            }
                       System.out.println("finished"+subs.size());

                       String everything = sb.toString();
                       jTextArea1.append(everything);


            br.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

however this is the output and error i got,but result  change every time i run

```
attention
3742
attentive
3743
attentively
3744
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at subtitleseeker.NewJFrame.jButton3ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:180)
    at subtitleseeker.NewJFrame.access$200(NewJFrame.java:17)
    at subtitleseeker.NewJFrame$3.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:60)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
attentiveness
3745
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
attenuant
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping it with a debugger?

Comment: can you explain?i didn't get it

Comment: Inspect NewJFrame.java very closely at line 180.  Something there is null that you weren't expecting

Comment: 180 line is  parts = s.split("=");

Comment: You do `String line = br.readLine();` and then you never assign it another value again, instead you use `String s = br.readLine();` later on in your loop, never checking if it's null. You should be consistently using one or the other.

Comment: Can you copy your dictionary file with the part around the word `attentively` ?

Comment: @sbat i think your comment is reason to my error.can you tell me how to fix it

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha you have never used a debugger? Your world is about to get much better: which IDE do you use?

Comment: @rob I'm using net-beans .

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joWldbcp1So

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original code, you read in a line from the file and assign it to your `line` variable. You also check to make sure the line variable is not null in the condition for your while loop. However, you never update the value of your `line` variable, and instead you just read new lines into the `s` variable inside of your loop, never checking to see if `s` is null.

Here's your original code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = br.readLine();

while (line != null) {
    String s = br.readLine();

    parts = s.split("=");
    en=parts[0];
    sin=parts[1].split(" | ");

    sb.append("INSERT INTO `singlish`.`eng` (`eid`, `eword`) VALUES ('"+stpoint+"', '"+en+"');")
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

    System.out.println(en);

    for(int i=0;i<sin.length;i++) {
        sb.append("INSERT INTO `singlish`.`sng` (`eid`, `sword`) VALUES ('"+stpoint+"', '"+sin[i]+"');");
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    System.out.println(""+stpoint);
    stpoint++;
}
```

These three lines:

```
String line = br.readLine();

while (line != null) {
    String s = br.readLine();
```

Can be replaced with this one line:

```
for (String s; (s = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
```

So your code reads:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (String s; (s = br.readLine()) != null; ) {

    parts = s.split("=");
    en=parts[0];
    sin=parts[1].split(" | ");

    sb.append("INSERT INTO `singlish`.`eng` (`eid`, `eword`) VALUES ('"+stpoint+"', '"+en+"');")
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

    System.out.println(en);

    for(int i=0;i<sin.length;i++) {
        sb.append("INSERT INTO `singlish`.`sng` (`eid`, `sword`) VALUES ('"+stpoint+"', '"+sin[i]+"');");
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    System.out.println(""+stpoint);
    stpoint++;
}
```